# Extra entries ignored in axis legend

Tags: pandas, matplotlib

I’m trying to reproduce some plots [from this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=54XLXg4fYsc) with up-to-date data and superimposing points on the lines for measures taken by governments. Using pandas for the data, and to call the plot commands.

wI have no trouble plotting the lines and appropriate legends. I then add superimposed points, for which I defined these properties:

```
point_opts = lambda marker, color: {'label': '', 'color': 'w', 'marker': marker, 'markeredgecolor': color, 'markeredgewidth': 3, 'linestyle': None}
```

I would like to only add those to the legend once, instead of once per country, hence the empty label.

I then try to modify the legend as follows:

```
handles, labels = ax.get_legend_handles_labels()

for props in ({**point_opts(marker, 'black'), 'label': measure} for measure, marker in points.items()):
    handles.append(matplotlib.lines.Line2D([], [], **props))
    labels.append(props['label'])

ax.legend(handles=handles, labels=labels)
```

However this does not change the axis legends (and no error messages are shown). The values seem right however. For example, if I add a second plot, on the Figure:

```
fig.legend(handles=handles, labels=labels, loc='center left')
```

I then get the result below.

[image: Figure with 2 plots]

Why is this happening? How can I actually modify my plot axis? Using python 3.7.3 and matplotlib 3.1.3 on OpenSuse x64, if that’s of any relevance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ugh alright, I’ve found it… I was, somewhere later, moving the legend around with:

```
ax.legend(loc='center left', bbox_to_anchor=(1, 0.5))
```

Apparently that resets the legend content to whatever the plot commands put there, erasing andy manual additions.